# Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi', bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to convert a user inputted answer to MD5 and compare it to the MD5 hash I already have to see if it's the same, but I'm getting a syntax error

```
Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
```

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if you're right!
declare -x answer=6f22bf74918703932091343ba9c64402
echo "Enter your answer, follow by [ENTER]:"
read userAnswer
md5sum userAnswer > hashedAnswer 
if [ answer == hashedAnswer ] 
then
    echo "Correct! You're right! It was him! Maybe I shou----"
    echo "-You get run over, silenced before you can present your proof-"
else
    echo "Wrong, try again!"
fi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is syntactically valid. Is that your *exact* script? You have missed the `$` on usage of variables though and `hashedAnswer` is a filename not the hash value itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's my exact script, It throws the error at line 15, and also flags "': not a valid identifierrAnswer"

Comment: Ah. You have DOS line-endings in that file. Run `dos2unix` on it.

Comment: Ah yea, that works, thanks alot! I'm guessing this is because unix doesn't recognize where the line ends if I didn't create the file in unix

Comment: It sees the `\r` at the end as part of the value and then gets confused and when printing it sets the cursor back to the start of the line (that's why your error looks confused because it started printing over itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these two lines:

```
md5sum userAnswer > hashedAnswer 
if [ answer == hashedAnswer ]
```

to:

```
hashedAnswer=$(printf "%s" "$userAnswer" |md5sum)
if [ "$answer" == "$hashedAnswer" ]
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if you're right!
answer="b326b5062b2f0e69046810717534cb09  -"
echo "Enter your answer, follow by [ENTER]:"
read userAnswer
hashedAnswer=$(printf "%s" "$userAnswer" |md5sum)
if [ "$answer" == "$hashedAnswer" ] 
then
    echo "Correct! You're right! It was him! Maybe I shou----"
    echo "-You get run over, silenced before you can present your proof-"
else
    echo "Wrong, try again!"
fi
```

N.B: the answer here is `true`